# Want to return multiple column from User DefinedFunction

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN.USER] (@USER_ID INT)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(300) AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(300) = ''

Select  @RESULT =[USER_NAME] From USER
WHERE USER_ID=@USER_ID

RETURN @RESULT
```

I have to show `Username` in my combobox. However I also need `username_Id` values.

How can I set username for my result and also select user id values at the same time ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  I think there may be two. 1. How to return username & ID from a stored proc (we need the table structure) 2. How to display in a combo.

Comment: The properties of a `comboBox` allow this to be possible. Add `UserID` to the returned data. When you are creating the drop-down options based on your `SQL` - just specify the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` from the query results.

Comment: Why on earth do you even need a function for this? Can't you just perform a join as part of the query? I'll give you a hint: scalar functions can't possibly make your code any faster and in most cases they will make it slower. Encapsulation is fun and shiny but not always appropriate.

Comment: You are not only person who is the most clever Aoron.My code is so long , i just asked little one to solve my problem in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [FN.USERNew]
(   
    @USER_ID INT 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
Select  [USER_NAME] , username_Id  From USER
WHERE USER_ID=@USER_ID
)
GO
```

and then you can select the from function by writing following

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FN.USERNew] (1)
```

Comment: If i write return , return has red under line , it gives syntax error

Comment: ı try to use this function on my stored procedure.So if i write like , FN.USERNew(User_Id) AS UserData , i get syntax error

Comment: you cannot write `FN.USERNew(User_Id) AS UserData' as there will be  two columns returned and it cant be stored in on column

Comment: i will ask new question about this , please follow.

Answer (score 0):

That's a scalar function not a stored procedure, you use it in a select statement like this

```
SELECT Username(somevalue), ....
```

If you want write a stored proc then try the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser
    @USER_ID int
AS
SELECT [USER_NAME], username_Id, whatever ...
FROM USER
WHERE USER_ID = @USER_ID
```

Alternatively you could use a table function as per Dhaval's answer.

If you want data from other table just do a join e.g.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE GetUser
        @USER_ID int
    AS
    SELECT [USER_NAME], username_Id, whatever ...
    FROM USER u
    INNER JOIN OtherTable ot ON ot.id = u.otid
    WHERE USER_ID = @USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN.USER] (@USER_ID INT)  
BEGIN
Select  USER_NAME, USER_ID
From USER
Where USER_ID=@USER_ID
END
```

If you want to have both the values in your combobox, just set the combobox.DisplayMember As the Username description, and the combobox.ValueMember As the Username ID.

```
comboProject.DisplayMember = "USER_NAME";
comboProject.ValueMember = "USER_ID";
```